# Is it possible to configure create-react-app express.static options without ejecting?

Tags: reactjs, express

By default, when an empty folder exists, [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) triggers a `301` redirect adding a forward slash.

This is how I disable this redirect for custom [Express](https://expressjs.com/) servers.

```js
server.use(
  express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build"), {
    redirect: false,
  })
)
```

Is it possible to configure `redirect: false` when using [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) in development mode (`npm start`?

Having a look at the following headers, I guess Express is what `create-react-app` uses to serve the [SPA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-page_application) in development mode.

**Request headers when loading http://localhost:3001/privacy-guides**

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
X-Powered-By: Express
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Content-Length: 195
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'none'
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Location: /privacy-guides/
Vary: Accept-Encoding
```

Comment: What do you need exactlly? `create-react-app` will generate a set of static files that can be served from `express`. Are you talking about redirects on the `express` side?

Comment: @goto1 By default, if a folder exists within the `public` folder, CRA will redirect hits to that server to `folder/`. This is default for Express. I wish to disable this default when developing using `npm start`.

Comment: I don't think I follow with what you mean by "default." You don't need an `express` server to use `CRA`. Not quite sure what your setup is exactly here, so perhaps provide more information.

Comment: @goto1, I just updated my questions with more details. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Looks like `express` is indeed a dependency of the `webpack-dev-server`, which is what `CRA` uses in `development` mode. I am still unclear what you mean by "when an empty folder exists". I've used `CRA` countless of times and I never had issues with redirects you're talking about. Unless you ejected your `CRA` and have a custom `config` file, then I am not clear under what circumstances you're running into issues and what those issues are.

Comment: @goto1 I am indeed working on a non-standard use case... try adding an empty folder (a `test` folder for example) to the `public` folder of one of your CRA projects and try loading that URL (http://localhost:3001/test). Are you redirected to `http://localhost:3001/test/`?

Comment: If I have `public/test/index.html` then I am seeing the content of the `index.html` file when I visit `localhost:3000/test`. If the `test` directory is empty then I am just seeing my React application as normal. I am not seeing any redirects on my end. By the way what is the purpose for doing this?

Comment: @goto1 Can you please try with an empty folder? I am developing a GitHub-flavoured markdown CMS that handles paths a bit differently. When a folder is empty, I don't want Express to add a slash as I this isn't the behavior that I will code in production (where I have more control on `express.static` options). I believe I found the config option I need, but I don't know yet if I have to eject. https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverstaticoptions

Comment: I have tried with an empty folder - see my previous comment. Also, keep in mind, you're trying to change how **development server** behaves, which **should be used for development**, and **not in production**. I think you should approach this differently, but I am still unsure exactly what is that you're trying to do, so I am afraid I won't be able to help. The `public` folder is not meant to be used in a way that you're trying to use it - https://create-react-app.dev/docs/using-the-public-folder/#when-to-use-the-public-folder

Comment: Having a hard time explaining this concept here. Thanks a lot for your help @goto1. I'm considering deleting the question.

Comment: You mentioned `markdown` and `CMS` - if you need to treat those `markdown` files as a "`CMS`" where you create multiple pages from multiple `markdown` files, then I suggest looking into `Gatsby.js` - https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/adding-markdown-pages/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer, no.

As @goto1 pointed out, the following isn’t good practice, but helped me understand how things work under the hood in CRA.

When running CRA in development mode using `npm start`, [webpack-dev-server](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server) is used to serve the app. Webpack DevServer uses Express to serve files which explains why browsing to folders triggers a `301` redirect (see [express.static](https://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#express.static) `options.redirect`, default is `true`).

> Redirect to trailing “/” when the pathname is a directory.

I confirm adding the following to `node_modules/react-scripts/config/webpackDevServer.config.js` disables the redirect.

```js
staticOptions: {
  redirect: false
}
```

Editing this file manually is a bit of a hack but works. Unfortunately, the only legit way I could find of configuring `staticOptions` requires [ejecting](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/available-scripts/#npm-run-eject).

Answer (score 0):

`create-react-app` is a build tool, not a server. Its output is a set of static `html`/`js`/`css` files which you are free to serve in any way you want. (`npm run build`)

The only thing that somehow served with `create-react-app` is a dev server, which intended to be used only on developer machine, not in production. (`npm start`)

If you still need to override `create-react-app` configurations, then take a look on specialized tools like:

- https://github.com/timarney/react-app-rewired
- https://github.com/harrysolovay/rescripts
- https://github.com/gsoft-inc/craco

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Please have a look at my answer to @goto1’s question.

Comment: I believe that it isn't a `create-react-app` behaviour, but `webpack-dev-server`.

Comment: https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/blob/e291cd4922f66c5c69dfd1fd3839812cfa502de5/lib/Server.js#L340-L390
Here is the code that serves static in dev server.

Comment: Interesting, if this is the case, I don’t see a `301` redirect in that code. Strange isn’t it?